# How to iterate all the values in backgridjs and send it to server only once

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections, marionette, backgrid

i have used [backgridjs](http://www.backgridjs.com/) and i am able to populate values to grid. but when i want to send the existing values from UI to server it works fine but if i delete all the records available in grid and create new record(s) and collect all the values available in grid and put them in model like

```
get the total no of rows
 iterate one rows
 put the rows data in to a model
iterate till end of the row and put them in a collection.
```

Please help me to get this done.

Comment: 1) Please post some code. 2) Please also ask a more specific question. Point out what you've tried and where you are getting stuck. Its impossible for people to help you if you are not more specific.